# Maven javadoc plugin build fails. How to add add portlet-api dependency

Tags: java, maven

I have a vaadin project and I tried to configure javadoc plugin in my project. I added following plugin to build->plugins section of my pom.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ....
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run a `mvn install`, build fails with following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:jar (default) on project web-yaan-ui-base: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for javax.portlet.PortletResponse not found
```

It says that `javax.portlet.PortletResponse` class is not found, so I tried to add `javax.portlet` as a dependency to the javadoc plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

But, I still get the error.

Then I tried to add `portlet-api` dependency to the pom dependencies section, along with other maven dependencies. Then it worked.

But, my final war file does not depend on `portlet-api`, so I do not want it to end up in `WEB_INF/libs` of my war file.

So, how can I fix this build issue without making `portlet-api` a dependency of my final war file?

Comment: Hum... The porlet-api dependency should be within the plugin declaration, as you have already set it. Have you tried to specify the goal `javadoc` too?

Comment: @LittleSanti, Yes, I tried `mvn javadoc:javadoc` and it fails.

Comment: No, I meant that you try to add a `<goal>javadoc</goal>` within the plugin declaration.